# HtmlAgilityPack - Surround HtmlNode Collection with HtmlNode

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, html-agility-pack

In my C# .NET 6 Application i have the following html structure

```html
<div id="111">Div1</div>
<div id="222">Div2</div>
<div id="333">Div3</div>
<div id="444">Div4</div>
```

I use `HtmlAglityPack` to acccess and edit the html structure and now i want to surround all those `HtmlNodes` with another `HtmlNode`.

So now i have all those 4 nodes saved in a list:

```cs
List<HtmlNode> nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div").ToList();
```

How can i achieve an output like:

```html
<div id="surroundingNode">
    <div id="111">Div1</div>
    <div id="222">Div2</div>
    <div id="333">Div3</div>
    <div id="444">Div4</div>
</div>
```